# supersymmetry and quantum groups

Tags: quantum-groups, noncommutative-geometry, supergeometry

I have some background in non-commutative geometry (in particular, I am doing research in quantum groups) and I have of course heard several times about the concept of *supergeometry* and *supergroups*. Nevertheless, I do not understand the latter very deeply and the connection between non-commutative geometry and supergeometry is not entirely clear to me. Do you know some good text that would introduce supergeometry from the quantum group point of view?

Maybe slightly more concrete question: I have read on several places that the main idea of supergeometry is that one has two sets of variables – one being commutative and the other being anticommutative. Now, I suppose that *supergroups* are supposed to describe symmetries of such non-commutative spaces. Are supergroups special instances of quantum groups then? What I find quite confusing is that if I have a set of anticommuting variables, then I would suppose that the quantum group describing their symmetries would be something like $SL_q(n)$ or $O_q(n)$ with $q=-1$. But in the supersymmetry literature, one reads about some (ortho)symplectic stuff instead!

Comment: Thinking classically, we have the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ of the Lie group $GL_n$. The quantum group $U_q(GL_n)$ is a deformation of the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{gl}_n)$ of the Lie algebra. The quantum group is an algebra, not a group, and does not (to my understanding, although perhaps it is treated differently in the physics literature) describe the symmetries of a space. Are you sure they quantum group is what you want to look at? In my limited understanding of supergeometry, it is much closer to commutative geometry than it is to non-commutative geometry.

Comment: Well, there are more viewpoints on quantum groups. What I have in mind here are deformed function algebras rather than deformed enveloping algebras of Lie algebras (nevertheless, there is a certain duality between those concepts). For example, the $SL_q(2)$ (that is, a deformation of $SL(2)$, that is, the dual of $U_q({\rm sl}_2)$) describes the symmetries of the $q$-commutative plane $X_q$. That is, there is a coaction $O(X_q)\to O(SL_q(2))\otimes O(X_q)$, where $O(X_q)=\langle x,y,\mid xy=qyx\rangle$. Note that we have anticommutativity for $q=-1$. See Klimyk–Schmüdgen §4.1.3.